# In Chrome App webview, what is the permission string to browse local files?

Tags: webview, google-chrome-app

In the browser example (https://github.com/GoogleChrome/chrome-app-samples/tree/master/samples/webview-samples/browser). Is there a permission that can be set such that the user can browse to `file:///C:/` (like in the main browser)?

Comment: Interesting question, and it's probably not possible, but _why_?

Answer (score 1):

No. Webview can use local resources only from the root folder of the application and webview is not a local file system explorer. Read about [webview](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/tags/webview).